# Is an infinite linearly independent subset of $\Bbb R$ dense?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

Suppose $(a_n)$ is a real sequence and $A:=\{a_n \mid n\in \Bbb N \}$ has an infinite linearly independent subset (with respect to field $\Bbb Q$). Is $A$ dense in $\Bbb R?$

Comment: One can certainly rescale any linearly independent set (by individual scalars) so that they each lie in $[0,1]$...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not necessarily.  We can use recursion to construct a linearly independent set $A = \{ a_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ so that $a_n \in ( n , n+1 )$ for all $n$.  Such a set is clearly not dense, but even more it is a closed discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Even a Hamel basis $B$ for $\mathbb{R}$ may not be dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (just ensure that all elements of $B$ avoid some open interval), however unlike the simple infinite linearly independent case by the Baire Category Theorem $B$ cannot be nowhere dense (since we have $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} ( q + B )$).

Comment: thanks. your answer prevents any trivial fixes to the question.

Comment: @CutieKrait: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is a linearly independent subset of $\mathbb R$, for each $a\in A$ there is a positive integer $n(a)$ such that $n(a)>|a|$.  The set $\left\{\dfrac{a}{n(a)}:a\in A\right\}$ is a linearly independent set with the same cardinality and span as $A$, but it is a subset of $(-1,1)$.